# Facebook and Firebase login with authtoken are bypassed when I uninstall the app. Why?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-android-sdk

I am authenticating users with this strategy that can be found in many tutorials:

```
AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (accessToken != null && firebaseUser != null) {
    // user is logged in
} else {
    logout();
}
```

The logout method is something like this:

```
public void logout() {
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
    goLoginScreen();
}
```

And it kind of works...

However, I decided to simulate a new user in my devide and I did this with my account: I logged out, delete my account in the firebase and I uninstalled the app. When I return, however, this mechanism is bypassed. The logs of the facebook token and firebase user looks something like this:

```
facebook: {AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[public_profile]}
firebase: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzxxyy@a123456b
```

How can I solve this problem?